# How to find out what version of gfortran was used to compile a fortran .mod file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a .mod fortran file, and it was compiled using gfortran. I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to find out which version of gfortran was used to compile this file? I do not have any configuration log files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have module zlibm.mod.  You can do

% cat zlibm.mod | gunzip | head -1

GFORTRAN module version '14' created from zlibm/zlibm.f90

The important item is the module version number.  The
gfortran developers try to minimize changes to the module
format to maintain backwards compatibility across different
compiler versions

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just checked.  It seems gfortran 6 and 7 are at module version 14 while gfortran 8 and gfortran from the development tree are at version 15.  The version number likely changed with the introduction of user-defined IO.

Comment: Note that before gcc version 4.something gfortran's module files were not gzipped.

Comment: @francescalus at this point in time, people using 4.x ought to upgrade to at gfortran 7.2 or later, if not 8.1.

Comment: It is not always that simple. I consider myself an advanced user, I know how to compile GCC, I report bugs to GCC and so on and I am still forced to use 4.8 in several places.

Comment: @Vladimir, it is simple if one wants to make it so.  900 bugs have been fixed since 4.8.5 was released.  In addition, new features have been added such as user-defined IO.  If management is reluctant to upgrade, one should be able to constructed an compelling argument why upgrading is desirable.

Comment: @Steve Upgrading GCC means upgrading of MPI, and recompiling all other libraries one uses. To recompile MPI one needs to get th drivers to the local schedule system and the local network layer (Infiniband). That is not always easy and often one is at mercy of the local sysadmin. Often they provide some more recent GCC but they do not provide MPI compiled against this GCC version. Fortran MPI modules are then unusable.

Comment: I also encounter the problem of MPI being compiled with a different version of GCC in some systems which I am not the admin. It is annoying and indeed forces the user to use older versions.

Comment: @b-fg, How dare those gfortran developers fix bugs and implement features of the standard that require changes to the module file!  It is completely irresponsible of them.

Comment: Don't get me wrong Steve! I was just complaining about some sysadmins not being careful on the compilers version offered.